# ValueError for tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering with predefined inital_clusters

Tags: python, tensorflow, k-means

I tried to use predefined inital_centers for tensorflow's KMeansClustering. (In sklearn, it is very simple with  "KMeans(n_clusters=K, init=init)")

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
K=5
X = np.random.random((100,1))
m1 = min(X)
m2 = max(X)

init_c =  np.linspace(m1[0], m2[0], num=K).reshape(-1,1)
print(init_c)

km = tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=K, 
relative_tolerance=0.0001, initial_clusters =init_c)

def train_input_fn():
    data = tf.constant(X, tf.float32)
    return (data, None)

km.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

The output error is:

```
/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, expected_shape, constraint)
356           if not initial_value_shape.is_fully_defined():
357             raise ValueError("initial_value must have a shape specified: %s" %
--> 358                              self._initial_value)
359 
360         # If 'initial_value' makes use of other variables, make sure we don't

ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("ones:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)
```

So what is the right way to use predefined initial centers for Kmeans in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `numpy` array uses the same data type `float32` as expected from tensorflow

`init_c = np.asarray(init_c, dtype=np.float32)`

and for some reason you need to set

`use_mini_batch=False`